# Why is cron is not running xte?

Tags: linux

I am attempting to reload Iceweasel from a cron job. I can run the following from the command line; it successfully reloads the page in Iceweasel:

```
 xte -x :0 "key F5"
```

I need this refresh to happen every 5 minutes. So, I set up the following as a root user cron job; this one does not work:

```
 */5 * * * * xte -x :0 "key F5"
```

I also tried including the full path to xte

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/xte -x :0 "key F5"
```

Does anyone know the solution?

Comment: Don't use the root user's crontab. Use the crontab of the user running the X session. See [the crontab tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/crontab/info) for helpful debugging tips, like how to examine error logs and to test run a command in a cron-like environment.

Comment: I am getting 'No protocol specified, Unable to open display :0'

Answer (score 0):

I found that cron needs the user creds in order to run. I am running this crontab on a Raspberry Pi set up as a Kiosk. So, the logged-in user is "Pi"

here is what works for me:

```
 */5 * * * * DISPLAY=:0.0 XAUTHORITY=/home/pi/.Xauthority /usr/bin/xte "key F5"
```

I hope this helps someone.